# iAd not shown in repeatable way

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, iad

I am testing a Universal app (IOS 4.3) on both iPhone/iPad simulator. It has a simple list/detail view.
On the detail view, I show a UIWebView and a iAd.

Now the detail view shows a different UIWebView and an iAd, each time it is accessed..

My issue is the iAd appears on 1st/2nd and may be 3rd instance/showing of detail view..But it is not shown after the 2-3 views..

It says

> ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not
>   implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
>   UserInfo=0x62852c0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad
>   inventory unavailable}

Please let me know how I can fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to add, I am testing on Simulator...So I am referring to test iAd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the obvious possibilities first: Have you assigned a delegate and does that delegate have a didFailToReceiveAdWithError: method defined in it?

If those things are OK, then the next step would be a zombie check to see whether the delegate has been deallocated.

Comment: Well as I said, I do get to see the iAd for 2-3 times initially...So can the issue be what u have mentioned ?

Comment: Yes.  Especially look at your didFailToReceiveAdWithError: method since that's what the error message is complaining about.